# ¿Cómo detectar que no existe una base de datos SQLite y que arroje error?

Tags: java, sqlite

Tengo un problema al tratar de probar conexión a una base de tipo **SQLite**, mi método de conexión lo tengo en una clase llamada `nwSQLiteCnct` el cual es el siguiente:

```
public void connect(String url)
    {
    try 
    {
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + url);
        if (connect!=null) 
        {
            System.out.println("Conectado");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        System.err.println("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos\n"+ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

El parametro **url** de `connect` se lo paso con una variable que traigo de un `Propertie` que leo de la siguiente manera:

```
try
    {
        //Obtiene el archivo propertie
        arch = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/dbprop.properties");
        //Crea una nueva instancia del objeto Propertie prp
        prp = new Properties();
        //Carga el archivo arch en el nuevo propertie
        prp.load(arch);
        //Asigna la direccion de la BD guardada en el propertie
        DB = prp.getProperty("db");
        //Instancia la clase conexion
        cnct = new nwSQLiteCnct();
        //Se conecta
        cnct.connect(DB);
        if(cnct != null)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La conexion esta funcionando correctamente!", "Correcto!",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encuentra el archivo correcto de conexion!", "Error!",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException a)
    {
       System.err.println( a.getClass().getName() + ": " + a.getMessage() );
    }
```

Esto es todo lo que contiene el Propertie `dbprop.properties`:

```
db = /Users/soporte02/Desktop/AccessPROTimeNet.db
```

Mi problema ocurre en que si la base de datos no esta en la dirección especificada, se crea otro archivo igual aunque sin ningún dato ilegible, por lo tanto siempre lanzara que la base de datos esta en la dirección correcta aunque no responda al momento de hacer consultas. No se si alguien pudiera ayudarme o decirme si lo estoy haciendo de manera correcta o hay algo en que me estoy equivocando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La base de datos sqlite es, a final de cuentas, un archivo físico en disco. Lo que necesitas hacer es validar que el archivo exista para abrir la conexión, de lo contrario lanzar un error. Basado en tu código, esto haría el trabajo:

```
DB = prp.getProperty("db");
File baseDeDatosSQLite = new File(DB);
if (!baseDeDatosSQLite.exists()) {
    //puedes lanzar otra excepción y un mensaje más apropiado
    throw new IOException("Base de datos no existe.");
}
cnct = new nwSQLiteCnct();
//Se conecta
cnct.connect(DB);
```

Comment: Ya había intentado este método, el problema es que si muevo el archivo, de todos modos crean un archivo igual, aunque no tiene ningún dato y lo toma como que si existe.

Comment: Tienes que colocar la validación **antes de** iniciar la conexión.

Comment: Listo, si funciono, gracias.